# Notice: Trying to get property 'items' of non-object

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments

**Integration stripe.com with the symfony is not working**

I'm trying to add Stripe to my Symfony page but this error is happening:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcTO9.png)

I'm following Stripe.com Docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

**CompraController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// This is your real test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('API_KEY');

class CompraController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/compra", name="compra")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {   
        function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
            // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
            // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
            // customers from directly manipulating the amount on the client
            return 1400;
          }
          
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
          
          try {
            // retrieve JSON from POST body
            $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
          
            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
              'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
              'currency' => 'brl',
            ]);
          
            $output = [
              'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
            ];
          
            echo json_encode($output);
          } catch (Error $e) {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          }
        return $this->render('compra/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'CompraController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($json_str)` and check what you actually get since it seems like it's not a valid json object.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as a picture as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question